# Can QuerySelectorAll work on Dynamic added Content?

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I am trying to apply querySelectorAll on Dynamic Content.

I am implementing the code like below:

```
<div class="drag" draggable="true">hello</div>
<div class="drop"></div>
```

These tags are created dynamically on the page. QuerySelectorAll not working on both of these tags.

```
            var cols = document.querySelectorAll('.drag');
        [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
            col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
        });

        var colss = document.querySelectorAll('.drop');
        [].forEach.call(colss, function (col) {
            col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
            col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
            col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
            col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        });
```

My problem is that I am trying to apply code on these two div's but if these tags are static querySelectorAll is working but if I create these two div's dynamically they are not working.

I have applied this code from 
HTML5 Drag and Drop API reference[Link]: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: is the "." in `class=".drop"` a typo you made while posting here?

Comment: Whether the elements are created from the initial HTML or added later to the DOM tree doesn't make a difference. DOM is DOM.

Comment: the elements are added later to the DOM. If I try apply initially to the DOM it is working but not if added later.

Comment: I corrected class="drop". It was written by mistake. Thanks for informing.

Comment: If you mean that the elements are added into the DOM after you used `querySelectorAll`, then the answer is **No**. You will need to use event delegation.

Comment: The only way it wouldn't apply later is if you didn't rerun your querySelectorAll()+addEventListener() logic each time a new element was added.

Comment: "Can QuerySelectorAll work on Dynamic added Content?" No, and this is by design: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall

Comment: you can use the less-powerful getElementsByClassName() to fetch a live dom collection which WILL be live-updated as new elements are added. they won't get the event bound automatically w/o delegation, but your collection will be self-updating like getElementsByTagName and how you seem to want querySelectorAll to work.

Comment: @dandavis: But IE8 will fail, as it's not supported

Comment: @user2736012: so what? it's not like the drag and drop is gonna work in IE8 either. forests, not trees.

Comment: @dandavis: It can be shimmed. A live list can't.

Comment: I'll try to implement getElementsByClassName(). I hope it works fine. Can Anyone illustrate and help me more briefly. It will be a great help.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName() is also not working. :(

Comment: It seems like you need to run that code after the elements are added, not before.  Please make a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using jQuery.
Code below works best:

```
            $('body').on('dragstart', '.drgbl', function (e) {
            handleDragStart(e)
        });
        $('body').on('dragend', '.drgbl', function (e) {
            handleDragEnd(e)
        });
        $('body').on('dragenter', '.rght-element', function (e) {
            handleDragEnter(e)
        });
        $('body').on('dragleave', '.rght-element', function (e) {
            handleDragLeave(e)
        });
        $('body').on('dragover', '.rght-element', function (e) {
            handleDragOver(e)
        });
        $('body').on('drop', '.rght-element', function (e) {
            handleDrop(e)
        });
```

This jQuery code works very fine on the dynamic data as `.on()` works on handling dynamic data attaching handler very easily.

Thanks Everyone for me able to figure out the answer.

Comment: hi can you please share how did u configure the handleDrag, handleDrop, .... functions?